# ifstream runtime error when attempting to save the data into array

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

I'm having a problem when I try to read the external text file.
The displayed text is correct but when it comes to saving the data into an array, it seems to be wrong.

My input numbers are 4 2 8 0 2 3 0 4 0 5, but after looping through the array, a[i], only '48' appears.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void begin ();
void Process (string);

using namespace std;

int main()
{   

        begin();

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}

void begin (void){

string file = "data.txt";
Process(file);      
}

void Process (string file)
{

        int i=0,ch, n = 0, temp, a[50];


        ifstream infile;
        infile.open(file.c_str());
```

The error seems to be caused from here.

```
        if(infile.is_open())
        {

            cout << "File to be read: " << file << endl;
            cout << "\n\n";
            infile >> temp;
            while(!infile.fail())
            {
                cout << temp << " ";
                infile >> temp;
                a[i] = temp;
                i++;
                n++;
            }

        cout << "\n\n";
        cout << "This file has " << n << " numbers. \n\n";

        }

        else
            cout << "The file isn't available! \n\n";

        infile.close();
```

When I try to output the result, only 48 appears.

```
        for (int z = 0; z < i; z++)
        {
            cout << a[i] << endl;

        }
}
```

I'm new here. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your display loop is using `i` instead of `z` to index into `a` (this should be a good lesson on why variable naming is important!)  Change your display loop to this:

```
    for (int z = 0; z < i; z++)
    {
        cout << a[z] << endl;
    }
```

There are potentially more issues with your code, but this seems to be what is blocking you.  Consider renaming `i` and `a` to more meaningful things.  The time you will spend typing will always be dwarfed by the time you spend trying to understand what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this loop

```
    for (int z = 0; z < i; z++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;

    }
```

You always output one element a[i] instead of a[z]. Moreover element with index i was not assigned. The last assigned element is a[i-1].

Apart from this you do not save the first entered number in the array. You start to save entered data from the second number.

```
        infile >> temp; // <== this value was not assigned to an element of the array
        while(!infile.fail())
        {
            cout << temp << " ";
            infile >> temp;
            a[i] = temp;
```

Also this statement inside the loop

```
            infile >> temp;
```

can result in error. So after that there is no sense to write

```
            a[i] = temp;
```

because nothing was entered and in fact you will store the previous number in the next element.